# Let $H\leq G$ where $H$ is max simple. Prove either $G$ is simple or there exists a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups, maximal-subgroup

Question: Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a maximal, simple subgroup of $G$.  Prove that either $G$ is simple or there exists a minimal normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is simple.

Thoughts: If $H=G$ or if $H$ is trivial, then $G$ must be simple.   Otherwise, assume that there is a subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $H\subset N\subseteq G$.  I know that any group that isn't simple can always be split up between a normal subgroup and its corresponding quotient group, but the "maximal" and "minimal" stuff here is throwing me off.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: What does $H$ have to do with the question?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am not quite understanding your question... are you saying $H$ isn't necessary here?

Comment: You’ve said what $H$ is, then it is not used after. Every finite group has a maximal simple subgroup, so the mere existence of $H$ doesn’t change anything.

Comment: I think the comma matters. The OP wants $H$ to be maximal *and* simple. Not every group has such a subgroup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$G$ has maximal simple subgroup; show that exists $N$ s.t $N$ is a normal subgroup and $G/N$ is simple.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3122451/g-has-maximal-simple-subgroup-show-that-exists-n-s-t-n-is-a-normal-subgro)

Comment: It's a badly worded question, because saying "let $H$ be a ..." suggests that such an $H$ always exists, whereas the essential hypothesis is to assume the existence of such an $H$. How about: "Let $G$ be a finite group and suppose that $G$ has a simple subgroup $H$ that is maximal as a subgroup of $G$"?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki That ALMOST answers my question, but the "minimal" part is still a little iffy to me...

Comment: @User7238 I see the problem, but "minimal normal subgroup" is a very frequently used term for a subgroup that is minimal with respect to inclusion amongst nontrivial normal subgroups, so its meaning is not really in doubt.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahhh, that makes sense now.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is normal, take $N=H$. Otherwise choose any minimal normal subgroup $N$. Then $N\cap H=1$ since $H$ is simple and $G=NH$ since $H$ is maximal. Now $G/N\cong H/H\cap N\cong H$ is simple.

Comment: I think the first line should start with "If $G$ is simple..."

Comment: No, I wanted $H$ normal. It's now corrected